# Button position change its position if clicked - HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I ran into a CSS issue in the site I'm working with: `http://shontejtaylor.fix-it-buddy-clients.com/`

If you click the button under the Slider that says "POTENTIAL... TAP IT", It will change its active state to a different position.

**Q: How can I fix the issue using CSS only?**

Comment: in its `:active` state it has `top: 1px;`

Comment: @Cherniv: how did you know the answer?

Comment: "Inspect Element" in Chrome shows all element' css styles

Comment: Thank you, you gave me the hint. I didn't see that in inspecting element for more more than an hour. What I did is that, I applied top:auto; in the input button and finally, its okay now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click the button under the Slider that says "POTENTIAL... TAP IT", It will change its active state to a different position.

set the TOP into auto :-)

Answer (score 1):

Like Cherniv pointed out, the button has 1px assinged in "top" attribute. So what I did is I put
I just assigned the value of "top" to "auto". And it worked.

`#mc_embed_signup.horizontal .button{
  top: auto;
}`